# How to get the read and write speed of android RAM?

Tags: android, io, ram

I need to test the performance of android's ram. How can I get the read and write speed of android RAM.
Since I have root authority and busybox, the method can be a bash shell or an android app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own benchmark, or look up the statistics on benchmark providers such as [PassMask Android](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt_mobile.htm). Benchmark writing involves a lot of methodologies (rules to be followed to get a correct, meaningful, and reproducible result.)

Answer (score 0):

Measure memory speed doing what?  It depends on what instructions are handling the data and whether the access is sequential or random (or backwards). It can also vary with multithreading using one or multiple cores. The following has results of my three Android memory benchmarks  (and links to MP results).  These might help in deciding what to do.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm#anchorStart